# Dictionary seems ok , but function returns "List index out of range"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure why this function is returning "List index out of range" Since it seens ok. What the function does is basically work the content of the file.txt to create a dictionary with the values.

Resuming, the function will transform the content of the file.txt:

```
access_1;test_group_1,test_group_2
```

to:

```
[{'groups': 'test_group_1,test_group_2\n', 'acl': 'access_1'}
```

The current code:

```
def prepare_list():
    try:
        input_list = []
        ins = open("file.txt", "r")
        for line in ins:
            values = dict()
            values['acl'] = line.split(";")[0]
            values['groups'] = line.split(";")[1]
            input_list.append(values)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error : %s" % e
    finally:
        return input_list
```

Output:

```
Error : list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm running the script on the folder where the file exists.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the whole file? Where does `"Access Control Lists Updated"` come from?

Comment: Are you sure every line has a `;`?. There might be blank lines for example (a trailing one?)

Comment: Check to see if you have lines that don't have a `;`.... You should probably change your exception to print the line...

Comment: Editing to remove the output of the other function who calls the prepare_list()

Comment: Maybe one of the lines in the file does not have a semicolon. See if you can print the line in the except clause. You could also enumerate the lines while iterating and print the offending line number

Comment: Stop blindly catching all exceptions. Doing so will help you find your errors.

Comment: Aside: if that's the format, namely semicolon-delimited, you could also use [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Comment: @poke I'm Still building the function =), but i'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = "a;b"
print data.split(";")     # Prints ['a', 'b']
data = "ab"
print data.split(";")     # Prints ['ab']
print data.split(";")[1]  # raises IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, if `;` is not there, it will return only one element. And if you try to access the second element, it will fail with that error.

If you know for sure that, *all lines will have `;`* in them, your whole program can be written like this

```
keys = ("acl", "groups")
with open("Input.txt", "r") as ins:
    input_list = [{k:v for k, v in zip(keys,l.rstrip().split(";"))} for l in ins]
print input_list
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to the solution, wich i'm posting it right now. Should i mark your answer?

Comment: @Thales Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and decide for yourself :) I would say, consider accepting the answer which helped you the most :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given by thefourtheye I was able to solve the problem testing if the file have lines with ; and striping new lines:

I could use the following correction:

```
def prepare_list():
    try:
        input_list = []
        ins = open("file.txt", "r")
        for line in ins:
        if line.strip() and ';' in line:
            values = dict()
            values['acl'] = line.split(";")[0]
            values['groups'] = line.split(";")[1]
            input_list.append(values)
            print "Correct : ",line
        else:
            print "line not correct. please fix it : ", line
            return False
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error : %s" % e
```

But it would print " line not correct, please fix it " for each new line, example with file with 4 new lines:

```
line not correct
line not correct
line not correct
line not correct
```

So, using the following i can remove the new lines, and clean the output to just show what is really wrong:

### file content:

```
access_1;test_group_1,test_group_2
access_2test_group_1,test_group_2
<new line>
<new line>
<new line>
<new line>
```

function:

```
def prepare_list():
    try:
        input_list = []
        ins = open("file.txt", "r")
        for line in ins:
            # go away new lines, GO AWAY
            if line.strip()
                # test for valid char in line
                if ';' in line:
                    values = dict()
                    values['acl'] = line.split(";")[0]
                    values['groups'] = line.split(";")[1]
                    input_list.append(values)
                    print "Correct : ",line
                else:
                    print "line not correct. please fix it : ", line
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error : %s" % e
```

output:

```
Correct   : access_1;test_group_1,test_group_2
line not correct. please fix it : access_2test_group_1,test_group_2
```

Thanks for the help thefourtheye :)